# Adding `after` block in rspec helper module

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a module of helpers which is `include`'d in an `RSpec.describe` block. Most methods in there are related to managing logged in / logged out status, so I'd like to make sure anything using that helper automatically cleans up the global state to avoid leaking doubles/mocks.

But every example I see [in the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) seems to be about adding just the helper methods, not extra `before` / `after` blocks.

Can I add an extra `after` block which won't override the existing ones from the helper module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, something like this should do the trick. (Example is that first one on your link with `after` blocks added.)

**helpers.rb**

```
module Helpers
  def help
    :available
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.after(:each) do
      puts "after in helpers.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

**example.rb**

```
require './helpers'
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Helpers
end

RSpec.describe "an example group" do
  after(:each) do
    puts "After in example.rb"
  end

  it "has access to the helper methods defined in the module" do
    expect(help).to be(:available)
  end
end
```

and then running it

```
$ rspec example.rb
# After in example.rb
# after in helpers.rb
# .
# Finished in 0.00196 seconds (files took 0.07939 seconds to load)
# 1 example, 0 failures
```

If I misunderstood the question, let me know and I can clarify further or alter the example

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**. Every `before | after` block created inside your test will run before the `before | after` block on **Helper** file.

So your **blocks** will not override the **helper** blocks.